# Vite monorepo - internal dependencies with dev server

Tags: vite, monorepo, esbuild

I have a monorepo setup with Typescript, Lerna, Yarn Workspaces where I am introducing Vite.
Rough repo setup:

```
packages/
  app/
    src/
      index.tsx
      App.tsx
    package.json (`library` package is a dependency)
    tsconfig.json
    ... (further config files)
  library/
    src/
      index.ts (exports all single component files)
      Table.tsx
      Form.tsx
      Page.tsx
    package.json (`"main": "./dist/index.js"` to export from module)
    tsconfig.json
    ... (further config files)
lerna.json
package.json
```

Let's say, `app` imports `Table` component from `library` and renders it on a page.

Now, I start dev server in `app`. It uses natives ES modules which starts downloading all the required files (see Network in Dev Tools) - which in current setup leads to all files from `library` to be downloaded (not only `Table`, but also `Form` and `Page`).

Of course my repo is bigger than this example, and dev server becomes pretty unusable in this setup (downloading hundreds of files).

My current understanding of the root cause is that using `index` file in `library` as a main entry point of a package leads to downloading them all.

Vite's answer to this seems to be [pre-bundling](https://vitejs.dev/guide/dep-pre-bundling.html), which works "out of the box" for external dependencies, and [can be also set up for internal dependencies in a monorepo](https://vitejs.dev/guide/dep-pre-bundling.html#monorepos-and-linked-dependencies).

I tried pre-bundling but was not happy with the result. When you need to change smth in a dependency (`library`), it needs a force new start. Also, it is cumbersome to pre-bundle CSS files with come along with the components.

Is pre-bundling might be a good solution in such a case? Are there known recipes to make it more flexible?

After trying pre-bundling, I though I would be fine treating my internal dependencies as a source code, which is [default behaviour](https://vitejs.dev/guide/dep-pre-bundling.html#monorepos-and-linked-dependencies). However, this leaves me with an issue of too many HTTP requests due to the way my imports/exports work (as described at the beginning).

This brought me to re-organize how I export in my monorepo. I tried in `package.json` to [use `exports` option instead of `main` + subpath exports](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#package-entry-points). So my `package.json` in `library` is looking like this:

```json
{
  "name": "library",
  "exports": {
    "./*": "./dist/*.js"
  }
}
```

And the import in the `app` will have to change from `import { Table } from 'library';` to `import Table from 'library/Table'`.

This seems to do the job. However I am still a bit concerned if for a large package it would be easy to find an import you need using subpaths. For example, imagine a case with lots of auto-generated components. Re-exporting in `index` like I did before seemed to be more developer-friendly.

Do you think I am on the right track using subpath exports to avoid downloading all the "unneeded" files from an internal dependency? Or is there a simpler way to achieve this which I am missing?

Comment: I created in the past this project [Vue 3 and pnpm workspace boilerplate](https://github.com/ghiscoding/vue3-pnpm-workspace), it uses pnpm workspaces with `workspace:*` as dependencies, you can run the project and whenever something change in the lib, it rebuild the `dist` and is automatically available to other packages via `workspace:*` in `package.json`. Take a look at the project, it might give you ideas on how to achieve this, it doesn't reference Lerna but it's very easily pluggable

Comment: @ghiscoding thanks a lot for the reference! 
I switched to doing `vite build` instead of `tsc` for my library, which reduces number of files in internal dependency, as it all gets bundled on build.
Now I have another challenge: using "library mode" for `library` package produces build with a separate CSS file (`style.css` by default). I don't get how am I expected to hook it in my main app. In a "normal" Vite build, CSS stylesheets would be included in `index.html` and downloaded. But a "library build" produces no HTML file. Right now it sees that CSS is just "hanging in the air".